# Running two or more motors at the same time with PiFace Relay Plus and Motor Extra

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a question. I have a Raspberry Pi connected to PiFace Relay Plus and PiFace Motor Extra. Is it possible to run two or more motors at the same time?

I have no problem with running one motor:

```
import pifacerelayplus
import time

pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC)

pfr.motors[0].forward()
time.sleep(5)
pfr.motors[0].coast()
```

I also managed to run one motor and than next one:

```
import pifacerelayplus
import time

pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC)

pfr.motors[0].forward()
time.sleep(5)
pfr.motors[0].coast()
time.sleep(2)
pfr.motors[1].forward()
time.sleep(5)
time.motors[1].coast()
```

But I can't find out how to make both motors run at the same time. I tried this code, but that only runs the first motor, than the program ends and the first motor still runs and never stops. The second motor never starts to run.

```
import pifacerelayplus
import time

pfr = pifacerelayplus.PiFaceRelayPlus(pifacerelayplus.MOTOR_DC)

pfr.motors[0].forward()
pfr.motors[1].forward()
time.sleep(5)
pfr.motors[0].coast()
pfr.motors[1].coast()
```

I even tried to create another variable "prf2" for second motor, but it didn't help neither. I'm glad for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error when running the program?  Looking at the source code of pifacerelayplus, it is INTENDED to fail if you give two motor commands within 0.15 seconds, on the grounds that the startup surge of two motors at once is likely to be more than your power supply can handle.  A couple of short sleep()s should avoid this issue.

Comment: I didn't get any error message. but your suggestion worked. I added `time.sleep(0.5)` between individual motor commands and it works now.

Thanks a lot.